# How to check if a file is an .exe

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could do something like

```
if file.Exists("file path") 
   then message box.show("exists") 
else file.delete
```

Can I do something like that but to check if a file is an executable and if it does a command and if does not do another command? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about checking the file extension??

Comment: How can you delete a file if it doesn't exist..? But yes, you can check if it's an exe and do something to it. Look at [System.IO.FileInfo.Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Looking at the extension to check if file is an exe or not doesn't seem to be correct. I can change the extension of any file to any extension I like. So for example I could change the txt extension to exe.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour], and perhaps visit the [help].  All your posts have a score of 0 or less which will lead to problems for you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a foreach like this.

```
For Each file As String In
My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\folder")
    Dim extention As String =
    System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
    MsgBox("The file extension is " & extention)
Next
```

just check if extention is like .exe

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim filepath as string = ""
 If filepath.EndsWith(".exe") then
 //do something
 Else
 //do something else
 End if
```

Comment: I think you forget to add the description here. Please add the related description regarding your answer and kindly avoid dumping just code only.